# Filters on the dashboard don't work with the Spanish dashboard

Tags: magento2, filter, dashboard, translate

When I put the panel in Spanish the filters stop working:

[image]

Why can this be? And how can I fix it?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve this problem go to:**

vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Element/DataType/Date.php

**And replace in function convertDate:**

$dateObj = $this->localeDate->date(
new \DateTime(
$date,
new \DateTimeZone($this->localeDate->getConfigTimezone())
),
$this->getLocale(),
true
);

**To**

$dateObj = $this->localeDate->date($date, $this->getLocale(), true);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is only with the date filters, and this happens due to the format of the dates, because:

**Spanish**: June 1, 2020 -> 01/06/2020

**English**: June 1, 2020 -> 06/01/2020

And magento always filters with the English format, even if the panel is in Spanish. How can I change the format of the filter? or How can I change the format of the calendar to use ever english format?